# how get map value and keys which I got (let fieldVAlues =response.getReturnValue();) from the apex method(getPicklistValues)

Tags: apex, lightning, javascript, salesforcedx

### ComponentController

```
getPicklistValues : function(component) {
        // let fields = component.get("v.picklistfieldMap");
        let fields = new Map([
            ['v.typeMizerOptions' ,'TypeMizer__c'],
            ['v.colorOptions' ,'Color__c'],
            ['v.designMizerOptions' , 'DesignMizer__c']
          ]);
          for(var nameListOptionKey of fields.keys()){
            let action = component.get("c.getPicklistValues");
            action.setParams({ "ObjectApi_name" : 'Product2' , "Field_name" : fields.get(nameListOptionKey)});
            action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                alert('posle callbeck');
                // let err =response.getError();
                let state = response.getState();
                if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                    alert('SUCCESS getPicklistValues');
                    let fieldVAlues =response.getReturnValue();
                    alert(fieldVAlues.keys);
                    alert(nameListOptionKey);
                    component.set(nameListOptionKey,fieldVAlues);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
                    alert('fail');
                }
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        }
    }
```

### getPicklistValues(Apex Method)

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Map<String,String> getPicklistValues(String ObjectApi_name,String Field_name,String nameListOptionKey){ 

    List<String> lstPickvals=new List<String>();
    Map<String,String> OptionMap = new Map<String,String>(); 
    Schema.SObjectType targetType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(ObjectApi_name);//From the Object Api name retrieving the SObject
    Sobject Object_name = targetType.newSObject();
    Schema.sObjectType sobject_type = Object_name.getSObjectType(); //grab the sobject that was passed
      Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sobject_describe = sobject_type.getDescribe(); //describe the sobject
      Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> field_map = sobject_describe.fields.getMap(); //get a map of fields for the passed sobject
      List<Schema.PicklistEntry> pick_list_values = field_map.get(Field_name).getDescribe().getPickListValues(); //grab the list of picklist values for the passed field on the sobject
      for (Schema.PicklistEntry a : pick_list_values) { //for all values in the picklist list
        lstPickvals.add(a.getValue());//add the value  to our final list
      }
      for (String lstPickval : lstPickvals) {
        OptionMap.put(nameListOptionKey, lstPickval);
      }
    return OptionMap;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the outside scope is constantly changing, so only the last value will be used.

You can see this behavior in action with this simple script:

```
let x = [1,2,3];
let y;
x.forEach(v=>(y=v,setTimeout(()=>console.log(y),100)));
```

You'd see output like this:

```
3
3
3
```

Because we only have one `y`, all of the functions bind to the same variable, so only the last value is used. We can use Function.prototype.bind to fix this problem.

```
x.forEach(v=>(y=v,setTimeout(((z)=>console.log(z)).bind(this,y),100)));
```

Similarly, we'll just wrap your function up with a call to bind, and this will fix the parameters in position.

```
    action.setCallback(this, (function(field, response) {
        let state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set(field, response.getReturnValue());
        }
        else {
            console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
            alert('fail');
        }
    }).bind(this, nameListOptionKey));
```